# Trajectory of a projectile in 3d coordinate knowing the angle, the target position and with possible height offset

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

I'n not that good in math and physics sadly but I want to understand one problem I'm facing right now. I am in a situation with a projectile shoot from a random height on direction of a target with position $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ there $y_2$ could be offset in height. I know the initial angle of shooting and the distance.
Now if the situation is in 2D I did menage to understand how to solve it following this nice video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dc34eSc8kPA
so using the formula 
$$Y=Y_0 + V_{0y} t -\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$
$$X=X_0 + V_{0x} t -\frac{1}{2}at^2$$ where $a=0$ on $x$

I did solve it change $t=x/V_{0x}$ and substitute it on $y$ and managed to find the initial velocity $V_0$ that I used on the motion part of my script.
The problem is that my target could be set as well as my projectile on a $X,Z$ horizontal position, so how I could get the velocity component on $X$ and $Z$ to reach my target and of course I guess will change even my $V_0$ formula.

Thank you for everyone who will help me.

Comment: The first step will be to obtain the plane along which the projectile will travel.

Comment: sorry, I guess the plane you are refering to as it's not X,Y but  X,Z on Y. I had in mind to try to find the angle difference between the projectile and the target and use it for determinate the motion but I am not sure if it's going to help me out